# Visit path passing id with Capybara on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, path, capybara

I am working on a Rails project, where I'm using Rspec to unit tests with Capybara to visit the pages. I have this real url: `http://localhost:3000/teacher/courses/2778/audience` where `2778` is the course id and this page show the student (audience) in that course of the teacher logged in.

My `routes.rb` for this resource looks like this:

```
...
namespace :teacher do
  ...
  resources :courses, except: [:delete] do
    member do
      ...
      get :audience
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

And in my unit test I'm already logged in as a particular teacher and I have a variable `@course` which represents the related course, now, I need to go directly to that url or path. I've already attempted:

```
visit '/teacher/courses/@course.id/audience'
visit '/teacher/courses/' + @course.id + '/audience'
visit '/teacher/courses/#{@course.id}/audience'
```

but nothing of this has worked.

How can I visit this path?

Comment: Your tests are using the test database whereas when you hit the URL directly, you're using the development database. `@course` is probably not set in the test database

Comment: @MusannifZahir, actually, I had instance a course before with a factory with FactoryGirl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String interpolation requires double quotes `"` try:

```
visit "/teacher/courses/#{@course.id}/audience"
```

This will become `visit "/teacher/courses/12/audience"` assuming @course.id is 12.

Right now these are the issues.

**First example:** `visit '/teacher/courses/@course.id/audience'` is an explicit string so it is trying to visit `'/teacher/courses/@course.id/audience'` as the true URL.

**Second example:** `visit '/teacher/courses/' + @course.id + '/audience'` will raise `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String` because id is a Fixnum and cannot be implicitly converted.(could be solved by `@course.id.to_s` but that looks dirty)

**Third example:** `visit '/teacher/courses/#{@course.id}/audience'` is also an explicit string because of the lack of double quotes and will act the same way as the first except it is trying to use /teacher/courses/#{@course.id}/audience as the URL inclusive of the curly braces.

Also as @MusannifZahir pointed out you should make sure this course exists in your test db. My answer assumes this is not the actual issue.

Comment: You should also be able to use the path helpers - visit courses_audience_path(@course)   - or something like that

Comment: @TomWalpole you are correct although with the `namespace` this route would be `teacher_courses_audience_path(@course)` assuming he actually named the `audience` path `as: :audience`

Comment: whoops -- I missed the namespace as @engineersmnky points out, and it may actually be  teacher_audience_course_path(@course)  since audience is actually shown as being a member method on the courses controller  (rake routes will show all the available path names)

Comment: I can use this format path from my structure on my `routes.rb`? I mean, if there are some `member` or `collection` nested in my routes file, I could use a path which has also that structure? @TomWalpole @enginnersmnky

Comment: Yes -- in your tests you should have access to all the path helpers you would in your controllers.

Comment: @TomWalpole and I missed the member portion so I think your route is accurate now `teacher_audience_course_path(@course)`

Comment: Perfect! both ways had worked! Thanks @TomWalpole and engineersmnky